# Have .vagrant folder one directory up

Tags: vagrant

Vagrant will create a directory called `.vagrant` in the same path where the `Vagrantfile` is located, where it stores information and boxes states.

I would like to have this directory stored in another location, the best option being a directory up (`../.vagrant`), defined in the `Vagrantfile`.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using the [`VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH` environmnent variable](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/other/environmental-variables.html#vagrant_dotfile_path)

> `VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH` can be set to change the directory where Vagrant stores VM-specific state, such as the VirtualBox VM UUID. By default, this is set to `.vagrant`. If you keep your Vagrantfile in a Dropbox folder in order to share the folder between your desktop and laptop (for example), Vagrant will overwrite the files in this directory with the details of the VM on the most recently-used host. To avoid this, you could set `VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH` to `.vagrant-laptop` and `.vagrant-desktop` on the respective machines. (Remember to update your `.gitignore`!)

Looking at https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3705#issuecomment-218569456 you can set this variable from your `Vagrantfile` - for example

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH = "#{ENV['HOME']}/project/vagrant/.vagrant";    
currpath = ENV['VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH'];
if(currpath.nil?)
    currpath = '.vagrant';
end
puts currpath #debugging
if(currpath != VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH)
    ENV['VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH'] = VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH
    ret = system "vagrant",*ARGV
    FileUtils.rm_r(currpath)
    if(ret)
      exit
    else
      abort "Finished"
    end
end

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  ...
end
```

I believe on windows, the `HOME` variable is called `HOMEPATH`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting environment variable for Vagrant, specifically [VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/other/environmental-variables.html#vagrant_dotfile_path).

So in this case:

```
cd /path/to/Vagrantfile
export VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH=../.vagrant
vagrant up
```

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to set this value in `Vagrantfile` in some way?

Comment: Not as far as I know. You could wrap the environment variable set and the vagrant up in a shell script easily enough though.

Comment: I did like you said but it causes the following error: `Invalid argument @ dir_s_mkdir - C:/Users/Bruno Finger/repos/DGuardWeb/".. (Errno::EINVAL)` I believe the script which creates the folder is not prepared for arguments containing things like `../`.

Comment: That is strange, because it works on the Mac I tested it on. A narrow case of 'it worked on machine' I suppose. It is possible that those scripts aren't as robust on Windows. Regardless, in your shoes I'd consider logging a bug against the Vagrant project: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues